# BeautifulSoup returns a strange value

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Here is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import openpyxl



r = requests.get("https://www.hemnet.se/bostader? 
location_ids%5B%5D=18045&item_types%5B%5D=bostadsratt")



soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")

for pris_kvd_rum in soup.find_all("div", class_="listing-card__attribute 
listing-card__attribute--primary"):


  pris = pris_kvd_rum.text

  lista = [pris]


  print(pris)
  print(lista)
```

What I want to do is print the pris-variable to excel. When you put the pris-variable in a list you can see that the price have a value of both the price and a value that for example is: 1\xa0450\xa0000\xa0kr. This makes it so that I can't treat or convert it to a number in excel. Does anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

So if I understand correctly what happens is that you need to decode the string and the only extract the number part of it, so you would need to install the library unidecode then extract each digit in the string to form the number

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import openpyxl
import locale
#regular expressions library
import re
#decoding library
import unidecode

r = requests.get("https://www.hemnet.se/bostader? location_ids%5B%5D=18045&item_types%5B%5D=bostadsratt")



soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")

for pris_kvd_rum in soup.find_all("div", class_="listing-card__attribute listing-card__attribute--primary"):


  pris = pris_kvd_rum.text
  print(pris)


  pris = unidecode.unidecode(pris)
  if ',' in pris:
    pris = re.findall(r"\d*\,\d*", pris)
    pris = float(pris[0].replace(',','.'))
    print(pris)
  else:
    pris = re.findall(r"\d+.", pris)
    pris = [x.strip(' ') for x in pris]
    pris = int(''.join(map(str,pris)))
    print(pris)
```

Comment: Thank you for showing me this! One problem is that it takes the 2 in m², so if it is for example 84,5 m², the outcome will be 8452. But I guess I can adjust that with formulas in excel. But maybe you have a solution for that too in python?

Comment: That's a little more complicated, I used regular expressions to look up for numbers I just edited the answer